# 2 блока разной высоты в одном ряду

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, что бы блоки были на одном уровне ( т.к. они на одном уровне по нижней стороне) без задания статической высоты и без флоатов

```css
  body .mid-wrapper .mid-container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center; }
    body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: -webkit-center;
      width: 40%; }
      body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container .block-img {
        min-height: 160px; }
      body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container .block-header {
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-bottom: 20px; }
      body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container .block-text {
        text-align: left;
        width: 70%; }
      body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container .btn-main span {
        left: 36%; }
        img{width:100px;height:100px;}
```

```html
  <div class="mid-wrapper">
      <div class="mid-container">

        <div class="block-container">
          <div class="block-img">
            <img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/04/13/00/331D901800000578-3536787-image-a-11_1460503122350.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="block-header">
            text text text text 
          </div>
          <div class="block-text">
            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
          </div>
          <div class="btn-link">
            <div class="button btn-main"><span> Sign Up</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="block-container">
          <div class="block-img">
            <img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/04/13/00/331D901800000578-3536787-image-a-11_1460503122350.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="block-header">
            text text text 
          </div>
          <div class="block-text">
            text text text text text text text text 
          </div>
          <div class="btn-link">
            <div class="button btn-main"><span> Sign Up</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```css
  body .mid-container {
display:flex;
align-items:flex-start;
width: 100%;
text-align: center; }
  body .mid-wrapper .mid-container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center; }
    body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: -webkit-center;
      width: 40%; }
      body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container .block-img {
        min-height: 160px; }
      body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container .block-header {
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-bottom: 20px; }
      body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container .block-text {
        text-align: left;
        width: 70%; }
      body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container .btn-main span {
        left: 36%; }
        img{width:100px;height:100px;}
```

```html
  <div class="mid-wrapper">
      <div class="mid-container">

        <div class="block-container">
          <div class="block-img">
            <img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/04/13/00/331D901800000578-3536787-image-a-11_1460503122350.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="block-header">
            text text text text 
          </div>
          <div class="block-text">
            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
          </div>
          <div class="btn-link">
            <div class="button btn-main"><span> Sign Up</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="block-container">
          <div class="block-img">
            <img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/04/13/00/331D901800000578-3536787-image-a-11_1460503122350.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="block-header">
            text text text 
          </div>
          <div class="block-text">
            text text text text text text text text 
          </div>
          <div class="btn-link">
            <div class="button btn-main"><span> Sign Up</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 body .mid-wrapper .mid-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block; 
    position: relative;
    text-align: center; }
    body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container {
      text-align: -webkit-center;
      width: 40%; }
      body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container .block-img {
        min-height: 160px; }
      body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container .block-header {
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-bottom: 20px; }
      body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container .block-text {
        text-align: left;
        width: 70%; }
      body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container .btn-main span {
        left: 36%; }
        img{width:100px;height:100px;}      
 body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container:last-child
        {
        border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,1);
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:42%;
        }
```

```html
   <div class="mid-wrapper">
      <div class="mid-container">

        <div class="block-container">
          <div class="block-img">
            <img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/04/13/00/331D901800000578-3536787-image-a-11_1460503122350.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="block-header">
            text text text text 
          </div>
          <div class="block-text">
            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
          </div>
          <div class="btn-link">
            <div class="button btn-main"><span> Sign Up</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="block-container">
          <div class="block-img">
            <img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/04/13/00/331D901800000578-3536787-image-a-11_1460503122350.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="block-header">
            text text text 
          </div>
          <div class="block-text">
            text text text text text text text text 
          </div>
          <div class="btn-link">
            <div class="button btn-main"><span> Sign Up</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body .mid-wrapper .mid-container {
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    margin:0 auto;}
    body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container { 
      border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,50%,1);
      text-align: -webkit-center;
      width: 40%; }
      body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container .block-img {
        min-height: 160px; }
      body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container .block-header {
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-bottom: 20px; }
      body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container .block-text {
        text-align: left;
        width: 70%; }
      body .mid-wrapper .mid-container .block-container .btn-main span {
        left: 36%; }
        img{width:100px;height:100px;}
```

```html
<div class="mid-wrapper">
      <div class="mid-container">

        <div class="block-container">
          <div class="block-img">
            <img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/04/13/00/331D901800000578-3536787-image-a-11_1460503122350.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="block-header">
            text text text text 
          </div>
          <div class="block-text">
            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
          </div>
          <div class="btn-link">
            <div class="button btn-main"><span> Sign Up</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
  
        <div class="block-container">
          <div class="block-img">
            <img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/04/13/00/331D901800000578-3536787-image-a-11_1460503122350.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="block-header">
            text text text 
          </div>
          <div class="block-text">
            text text text text text text text text 
          </div>
          <div class="btn-link">
            <div class="button btn-main"><span> Sign Up</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```